# Save a video in Cache

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, caching

Is there a way to save a video in Cache Memory and then retrive the same when needed ?

```
NSCache *memoryCache; //assume there is a memoryCache for images or videos
NSString *urlString = @"http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg";
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"A"] ofType:@"mov"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

NSData *downloadedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^
{
    if (downloadedData)
    {
        // STORE IN FILESYSTEM
        NSString* path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
        NSString *file = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"B.mov"];
        [downloadedData writeToFile:file options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];
        NSLog(@"Cache File : %@", file);

        // STORE IN MEMORY
        [memoryCache setObject:downloadedData forKey:@"B.mov"];
    }
    // NOW YOU CAN CREATE AN AVASSET OR UIIMAGE FROM THE FILE OR DATA

});
```

I found this code on Stack Overflow, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Op , you got your answer ?

Comment: Still have confusion with the behaviour of Cache Directory

Comment: Is it that the contents of the Cache Directory will be wiped off if the app is terminated ?

Comment: what confusion you have ? you can describe it in you current question with a edit section.

Comment: I just asked my confusion in the comment above

Comment: No , it will not removed when app terminated. you can read it in reference answer. here is a link [NSCache](http://nshipster.com/nscache/). the cache is most often purged when the app goes to background or when you add more large elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` for downloading video or image , directly write to temp directory.

> During download, the session periodically calls the delegate’s 
>   `URLSession:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:`
>   method with status information.
>
> Upon completion, the session calls the delegate’s `URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:`
>   method or completion handler. In that method, you must either open the file for 
>   reading or move it to a permanent location in your app’s sandbox container directory.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request
                                                     completionHandler:
^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentsPath];
    NSURL *documentURL = [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response 
    suggestedFilename]];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtURL:location
                                            toURL:documentURL
                                            error:nil];
  }];

  [downloadTask resume];
```

[NSURLSessionDownloadTask Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDownloadTask_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLSessionDownloadTask)

Answer (score 0):

NSCache is like NSDictionary but empties itself if it detects wasted memory. Here are the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/

Even small videos are large so it is probably immediately dumping it from memory or refusing to store it in the first place.

You could store the video in an NSDictionary that is stored in some type of singleton but this leads to the next issue: I can't fathom any reason to store a video in memory for an iOS device. There is little memory -- much less than a desktop computer -- but all iOS devices have exceptionally fast disk I/O. That is, it's extremely expensive to cache a video on an iOS device and adds no discernable benefit.

So, you can create a singleton, add a dictionary, and store it there. But you really shouldn't: just retrieve it from disk when needed.